# Assign margin-left using element's own width

Tags: jquery, css

I want to set the `margin-left` of an element to negative half the width of itself. This gets the document's width instead:

```
$("#services .backPanel > div").css({
    'margin-top': -($(this).height()/2),
    'margin-left': -($(this).width()/2)
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

### css

```
#services{
    margin: 127px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#services .services{
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px 9% 0 9%;
}

#services .backPanel{
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    z-index: 80;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f9f8f8;
}

#services .backPanel div{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

### html

```
<div id="services">
    <div class="services">
        <h1>Services</h1>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="frontPanel design">
                    <h3>Design and development</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="backPanel">
                    <div>
                        <h3>Design and development</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget viverra massa.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## SOLVED IT

Turns out that I hadn't taken into account the css `transition` property that was set to the parent `.backPanel`, which caused the function to read the element's width and height at it was being loaded. With the `transition` set for all properties, the inner `div` was still growing from 0 towards its final width and height.

*Note for future reference*: Always take into account the transition for the animations of objects when reading their dimensions.

Comment: The `margin-top` and `margin-left` are set to negative half of the document's height and width. Let me add some css for context

Comment: Can you put your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: One problem is that your CSS is using the class selector `.services` while your jQuery is using the ID selector `#selector`. Are you mixing them up? Could you post your HTML?

Comment: I didn't notice i posted the css with the class selector. In fact, the class is inside another div with id `#services`. Also, all of this is nested inside a huge html structure. I wouldn't want to overload the post with unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I hadn't taken into account the css `transition` property that was set to the parent `.backPanel`, which caused the function to read the element's width and height at it was being loaded. With the transition set for all properties, the inner div was still growing from 0 towards its final width and height.

***Note for future reference***: Always take into account the transition for the animations of objects when reading their dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking `$(this)` is pointing to `window` in your case. Try:

```
$("#services .backPanel > div").each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    element.css({
        'margin-top': -(element.height()/2),
        'margin-left': -(element.width()/2)
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/peQ2R/

Comment: I tried this with a `.css('margin-top': function(){return -($(this).height()/2)}, 'margin-left': function(){return -($(this).width()/2)});`and got the same result that I got with your code. This is the closest approach but the values returned are nowhere near the actual values it is supposed to return.

Comment: Solved it by altering the transition property of the `backPanel`object. Your code made the final cut though! Thanks!