# Margin 50% of its own size?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a custom slider control within a div. Right now I'm using javascript to move the knob around and to respond to all container manipulations (like resize). It occurred to me that if I could set the knob to have a margin-right of -50% of its own size(so that when its left is 0% its center, instead of its left edge would sit on the leftmost end of the range), I could ditch a lot of manual manipulation.

I tested it by setting the margin in pixels and it works great, except i still have to update the margin every time the control is resized, is there a way in css to set its right margin to -50% of its own width?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign margin-left using element's own width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723720/assign-margin-left-using-elements-own-width)

Comment: never mind, already found a solution - transform: translate(-50%, 0); (and its chrome/ie equivalents)

Comment: Note that it might be a good idea to answer your own question ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer ) if you found a solution yourself. By doing so, you won't attract any more readers that think your question is unanswered (like me) and this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
```

to do the deed! It moves the element in relation to its pivot, in this case it moves the elements horizontal center to its pivot which is what I wanted.